# Ex 3.5.12 from Tao analysis book (rigorous proof of recursive definitions)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}$Exercise 3.5.12.  This exercise will establish a
rigorous version of Proposition 2.1.16. Let $f : \N×\N → \N$ be a function, and
let $c$ be a natural number. Show that there exists a function $a : \N → \N$
such that $a(0) = c$ and $a(n+1) = f(n,a(n))$ for all $n ∈ \N$, and furthermore
that this function is unique.  (Hint: first show inductively, by a modification
of the proof of Lemma 3.5.12, that for every natural number $N \in \N$, there
exists a unique function $a_N \colon \{n ∈ \N : n ≤ N\}\to\N$ such that $a_N(0)
= c$ and $a_N(n+1) = f(n,a_N(n))$ for all $n \in \N$ such that $n<N$.)

---

Lemma 3.5.12 (Finite choice). Let $n \ge 1$ be a natural number, and for each
natural number $1 \le i \le n$, let $X_i$ be a non-empty set. Then there exists an
$n$-tuple $(x_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ such that $x_i \in X_i$ for all $1 \le i \le n$. In other words,
if each $X_i$ is non-empty, then the set $\prod_{i\le i\le n} X_i$ is also non-empty.

*Proof*

We induct on $n$. Starting with the base case $n = 1$; the claim
    follows from Lemma 3.1.6 (why?) now suppose inductively that the claim
    has been proven for some $n$, we will prove it for $n+1$.

Let $X_1,\dots,X_{n+1}$ be a collection of non-empty sets.
    By the inductive hypothesis, we can find an $n$-tuple $(x_i)_{1\le i\le n}$
    such that $x_i \in X_i$ for all $1 \le i\le n$. Since $X_{n+1}$ is
    nonempty, by Lemma 3.1.6 we may find an object $a$ such that $a \in
 X_{n+1}$. If we thus define the $(n+1)$-tuple $(y_i)_{1\le i \le n+1}$
    by setting $y_i := x_i$ when $1 \le i \le n$ and
    $y_{n+1} := a$, it is clear that $y_i \in X_i$ for all $i$
    with $1 \le i \le n+1$; this proves the claim.

---

My attempted solution was to consider the function $a_N$ as an
$N$-tuple and use mathematical induction on $N$:

Base case: $a_0(0) = c$ by definition.

Inductive hypothesis: $a_N(0)=c$ and $a_N(n+1) = f(n,a(n))$ for all
$n \le N$. It follows from the order of $\N$ that there exists an $n$
such that $a_N(N) = f(n,a(n))$.

Then I show by the same method of the lemma that $a_{N+1}(n) = a_N(n)$
for $n \le N$ and that $a_{N+1} = f(N,a(N))$ from the inductive hypothesis.
Is my attempt true. If not I would consider a proof that follows the hint.

Note
The question was asked here

[Proof of a proposition about recursion definition (Terence Tao's Analysis I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778816/proof-of-a-proposition-about-recursion-definition-terence-taos-analysis-i)

but answers doesn't follow the hint.

Comment: The answers to the mentioned question doesn't follow the hint given by Tao.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quite confused by the sketch of your proof. (As an aside, the fact that Tao writes $n$++ to mean $n+1$ is somewhat irksome.)

Let's prove the hint. As you say, the base case $n=0$ is clear: define the function $a_0 \colon \{0\} \to \mathbb N$ by $a_0(0) = c$.

Now for the inductive set. We assume we have a function $a_N \colon\{n \in \mathbb N : n \le N\} \to \mathbb N$ such that $a_N(0) = c$, and $a_N(n+1) = f(n,a_N(n))$ for all $n < N$. What we need to do is define a *new* function $a_{N+1}\colon \{n\in \mathbb N : n \le N+1\} \to \mathbb N$ that also works.
To do so, we can set $a_{N+1}(n) := a_N(n)$ when $n \le N$. Finally, *define* $a_{N+1}(N+1) := f(N,a_{N}(N))$.

Now we need to check that $a_{N+1}(0) = c$ and that $a_{N+1}(n+1) = f(n,a_{N+1}(n))$ for all $n < N+1$. This is practically already done for us; I leave it to you.

Finally, we need to check the uniqueness of this function. I will also leave it to you.

Then, notice that if $N$ and $N'$ are natural numbers and $n \le N$, $n \le N'$,
$a_N(n) = a_{N'}(n)$. So we may define the function $a\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ to be $a(n) := a_n(n)$. One also checks uniqueness.

Comment: (Now we need to check that aN+1(0)=c and that aN+1(n+1)=f(n,aN+1(n)) for all n<N+1. This is practically already done for us; I leave it to you.) I proved this by induction hypothesis ,and the uniqueness by equality of functions,but I don't understand the last paragraph

Comment: what about it is confusing to you?

Comment: (Then, notice that if N and N′ are natural numbers and n≤N, n≤N′, a$_N$(n)=a$_N′$(n). So we may define the function a:N→N to be a(n):=a$_n$(n). One also checks uniqueness.). So do you mean that.  a$_N$(n)=a$_N$$_′$(n) for all n≤N,n≤N' and what do you mean by a(n):=a$_n$(n).

Comment: OH, I guess this is a point about set theory about which I am never picky, so I have gone faster than Tao would like me to.

Comment: I looked for it and concluded that you mean we define $a(n)$ to be the function $a$$_n$$(n)$ obtained from n by the hint .Is this right

Comment: Yes. Maybe to match the notation from earlier, I want the function $a$ evaluated at $N$ to be equal to $a_N(N)$.

Comment: @Rylee Lyman so you mean a function $a_{n}$: {$n\in N : n\le n$} ---> $N$, which would of course just be a function from $N$ to $N$? I'm not sure if it's valid to be using the variable $n$ like that, since it's just a dummy variable.

Comment: I'm curious. Is using $n\text{++}$ to denote Peano's successor function irksome for its insertion of computing notation into mathematics. Or is it because you know, like me, that it should have been $\text{++}n$, since `n++` means "evaluate the variable first, then increment it", while `++n` means "increment first, then evaluate". So $a(n\text{++}) = f(n,a(n))$ should properly translate to $a(n) = f(n+1, a(n+1))$?