# Why is the hint needed in Exercise 3.5.12 in Tao's Analysis 1

Tags: real-analysis

I did see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3352748/ex-3-5-12-from-tao-analysis-book-rigorous-proof-of-recursive-definitions) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778816/proof-of-a-proposition-about-recursion-definition-terence-taos-analysis-i) but I still don't really get it.

The question is
Let f : N×N → N be a function, and let c be a natural number. Show
that there exists a function a : N → N such that
a(0) = c
and
a(n++) = f(n, a(n)) for all n ∈ N,
and furthermore that this function is unique.

The hint given is
Show inductively that for every natural number
M ∈ N, there exists a unique function a : {n ∈ N : n ≤ M} → N such
that aM(0) = c and aM(n+1) = f(n, a(n)) for all n ∈ N such that n<M.)

My question is, why can't we just define a function a: N → N that obeys these properties.
Jut let a(0)=c and a(n+1)=f(n,a(n))
Then a is defined for every natural number, and is unique.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of a proposition about recursion definition (Terence Tao's Analysis I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778816/proof-of-a-proposition-about-recursion-definition-terence-taos-analysis-i)

Comment: I already looked there before but I don't get it. The reply says we cannot form the set {(n,α(n)):n∈N} even if a(n) is defined for all n, but I don't see why not.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, why can't we just define a function $a:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ that obeys these properties. Jut let $a(0)=c$ and $a(n+1)=f(n,a(n))$ Then $a$ is defined for every natural number, and is unique.

The whole point of this exercise is to show that you *can* define $a$ in this fashion. The problem here is that you are just assuming it can be done. You don't get to assume that. You have to prove that there is a function $a$ with these properties.

If you take this description at face value, it requires an infinite process. You define $a(0)$ and then you define $a(1)$, and so on. Infinite processes are very problematic. Here is a famous example: suppose you have two infinite urns. One has a ball for every natural number, which is inscribed in some way on the ball. The other is empty. You start moving the balls from the full urn to the empty one. On each turn, you move the lowest two natural numbers in the full urn to the other urn. But once there you pull out the ball for the lowest natural number in that urn and discard it. Repeat this process infinitely. Once done, what is the state of the urns? The first urn is empty because you have removed all the balls. But even though the number of balls in the second urn went up by one every turn, when you are done, it must also be empty, because you discarded infinitely many balls from it, and did not skip any natural numbers. So you can determine for each ball the turn in which it moved from the first urn to the second, and the turn when it was discarded. All balls were discarded. To make matters worse, suppose instead you discarded the highest numbered ball in the second urn each turn. Under that scenario, the second urn is not empty at the end. Instead it contains infinitely many balls - either all the evens or all the odds, depending on whether or not you include $0$ in $\Bbb N$ (both definitions are in use). Yet in both cases, you put in two balls and removed one each turn - so strictly from a counting standpoint, they should be the same.

This is just one of many examples of why the concept of an infinite process (called a "supertask") is not a trustworthy foundation for mathematical concepts. Instead, infinite processes are avoided, and infinities must be approached with great care. For example, we define infinite sums $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)$, but how? This is *not* done by saying "add up all the terms". Instead we posit the existence of a value $S$ for the sum, and give a condition it must satisfy to be that sum: for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $N$ such that for all $m \ge N, \left|\sum_{n=0}^m a(n) - S\right| < \epsilon$. Note that this definition gets around the issue of infinite processes by swapping out the infinite process for an infinite number of comparisons instead. But each comparison is already well-defined, and by logic you can dispatch infinitely many of them at once, instead of one-at-a-time. For appropriately behaved sequences, we use the properties of real numbers (or other spaces we are working with) to prove the existence of the limit $S$.

This exercise is doing something similar for "inductive definition", showing by other means that there exists a unique function $a(n)$ which satisfies the initial condition and recurrence relation. This allows us to assert such a function exists without needing to actually perform the infinite process of defining it by the recursion. Just like the infinite summation of a series was swapped out for an infinite number of well-defined comparisons, the hint directs you to how you can swap out the infinite number of definitions for an infinite number of checks of an element in a set, each of which is also well-defined. And once again, that infinite number of inclusions can be settled en-masse using logic.

I won't reproduce the proof. It is available in the other thread. But the point is that it relies only on well-grounded constructions in set theory to prove that such a function $a(n)$ exists. And it is only after you have that proof that you can claim that $a(0) = c, a(n+1) = f(n,a(n))$ for $n > 0$ actually does define a function.

Comment: Your description of what a series is is very misleading, I'd say. The value of a series is not the sum of anything, but a limit — which we write as a sum simply because it has formal properties similar to sums. Thus saying «we posit the existence of a value $S$ for the sum» does not make any sense, for there is no sum.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez - I'm sorry, but I cannot respect that at all. *Everyone* uses the word "sum" to refer to a series. To call the extremely common terminology "very misleading" is ridiculous, especially since that very sentence *explicitly* points out that it is not an actual sum! Further, I expected the OP to know these facts. I was only reminding them to give an example about how the results of such supposed infinite processes are actually defined. I cannot see any point at all to your complaint. It is your comment that makes no sense.

Comment: I am not surprised that you do not see the point, to be honest. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez - if you could offer a point to see instead of a ridiculous claim faulting me for using extremely common terminology and pretending that I was supporting an idea that I explicitly denied in that very sentence, I'd be willing to hear it. But a smug proclamation that I don't understand something where you cannot demonstrate any such misunderstanding is just nastiness.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\NN{\mathbb{N}}$The point of the exercise is that one *cannot* define a function $f:\NN\to\NN$ by saying that

> $f(1)=1$ and $f(n+1)=2f(n)$ for all $n\in\NN$.

This is **NOT** a *definition* of a function, but a *property* of a function. What one can do is to show that *there exists a function which has that property* and, moreover, that there is exactly *one*. The hint gives you the standard argument used to do this.

Stackexchange does not let us use a font as big and as bold as one would need to properñy emphasize the fact that **NOT** above…

Giving a property of something does not define anything in general. For example, it does not work to say

> let $x$ be the real number such that $x^2+1=0$

for there is no such real number. Similarly, it does not work so say

> let $f:\NN\to\NN$ be the function such that $f(0)=4$ and $f((n-5)^2)=n+1$ for all $n\in\NN$

for there is no such function.

So when one wants to say, for example,

> let $f:\NN\to\NN$ be the function such that $f(1)=1$ and $f(n+1)=2f(n)$ for all $n\in\NN$

one has to prove that there is such a function.

---

(I'll write $[a,b]$ for intervals in the integers here)

Now suppose that you have a positive integer $N$ and you know that

> there is a function $h:[1,N]\to\NN$ such that $h(1)=1$ and $h(n+1)=2h(n)$ for all $n\in[1,N-1]$.

I claim that then

> there is also a function $g:[1,N+1]\to\NN$ such that $g(1)=1$ and $g(n+1)=2g(n)$ for all $n\in[1,N]$, and moreover the restriction of $g$ to $[1,N]$ is equal to the function $h$.

Indeed, we can define this function directly: we consider the set
$$\{(i,h(i)):i\in[1,N]\}\cup\{(N+1,2h(N))\},$$ prove that it is a function $[1,N+1]\to\NN$ and check that it has the required property.

In this way, by induction (one has to start it, I'll let you do that), one shows that

> for all $N\in\NN$ there exists a function $h_N:[1,N]\to\NN$ such that $h_N(1)=1$ and $h_N(n+1)=2h_N(n)$ for all $n\in [1,N-1]$

and that moreover these functions have the property that

> whenever $n$ and $m$ are elements of $\NN$ such that $n\leq m$ we have $h_m(n)=h_n(n)$.

Now we can consider the set
$$\{(n,h_n(n)):n\in\NN\},$$
check that it is a function $f:\NN\to\NN$ and that it has the property we want, namely,

> $f(1)=1$ and $f(n+1)=2f(n)$ for all $n\in\NN$.

The key fact that makes all this work is that in constructing the functions $h_n$ and the function $f$ I did not wave my hands at any point: I simply used the definition of what a function is, and the operations of set theory that construct sets from sets — in fact, I only used unions and pairings.

---

One can view a phrase like

> define the function $f:\NN\to\NN$ so that $f(1)=1$ and $f(n+1)=2f(n)$ for all $n\in\NN$

as a definition of a function through an *algorithm* that computes it. This does not eliminate the need to prove the exercise in Tao's book. Indeed, it is the fact that the claims of the exercise are true what give sense to *defining a function through an algorithm to compute it*. At some point one has to define what it means «to give an algorithm that defines a function» and it is that exercise, essentially, what one usually does.

There is a whole theory, that of denotational semantics, that deals with giving sense to this sort of «definitions». And, trust me, it is not  an easy task.